# Does Angular Child Routes inherit Parent Route Guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have the following route definition:

```
export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot([
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'child1',
            component: Child1Component
        },
    ]
},
]);
```

Will `child1` route inherit the canActivate guard from its parent?

Comment: It does not in a sense. But to access the child route, one must go through its parent so the parent guard wil always be invoked.

Comment: @HarryNinh, I was also thinking the same thing. In this case, I don't have to put the route guard in every child route since I wanted the guard to be executed on all routes